# How to share files between product installers to improve msi build performance

Tags: wix

I have many installer projects (MSI) that use the same files. Packaging the files into each MSI takes a lot of time, about 40 min.

The files are installed into each product's directory, so they are not "shared components" between different products. I should be able to uninstall one product without affecting others.

Is it possible to "package" the files once and include them in each product? Will it speed up the MSI build?

If so, how do I do it?